# Set Variable By InputBox error

Tags: vb.net, inputbox

Im trying to save a file to a forecd location ussing the following however im given an error?

```
  Dim FILENAME As String
    FILENAME = InputBox("Template name: ")
    'Writes values to new file...
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\MYFOLDER\" & FILENAME & ".txt")
```

Comment: What kind of error? Please, provide us some more useful informations

Comment: Without knowing your error it's tough to help you..

Comment: its in blasted dutch I have absolutly no clue to what it means..but i think it means somthing along the lines of Argument prompt cant be converted to type string???

Comment: Before Processing `FILENAME` check whether `FILENAME` is `empty` or `NOT`

Comment: thats just confused me because I thought I set that with FILENAME=inputbox? or (obviously) not?

Comment: The code works fine even if the filename is empty. Exception is received only if folder C:\MYFOLDER does not exist.

Comment: Err dont ask what happen, though I restart my PC and everythings working again? thasnks for your help guys :)